# Timeout error in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm testing the scalability of a block chain app that I am going to build using hyper ledger composer. I am using the basic-sample-network for testing purposes. I have installed the basic-sample-network using the tutorial found here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html. It is located on an aws instance running Ubuntu 16.04 with t2.xlarge storage. I setup a rest service on the aws instance, and started to spam requests to test the scalability. After a while, I got the following errors.

```
Unhandled error for request POST /api/org.example.mynetwork.Trader: Error: error trying to query chaincode. Error: Error executing chaincode: Failed to execute transaction (Timeout expired while executing transaction)
at channel.queryByChaincode.then.catch (/home/ubuntu/composer/my-network/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:758:34)

Unhandled error for request POST /api/org.example.mynetwork.Commodity: Error: error trying to query chaincode. Error: Error executing chaincode: premature execution - chaincode (my-network:0.9.2) is being launched
at channel.queryByChaincode.then.catch (/home/ubuntu/composer/my-network/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:758:34)
```

Any clue to what is causing this problem?

Comment: Can you attach the logs from the start of the run for the chain code container please.

Comment: Sorry for the long response. [link](https://github.com/ki0apa/Composer_Error/blob/master/err.txt)

Comment: I was also able to get `compose network ping` to work. Here is the response.

Comment: `Error: error trying to ping. Error: Deployed chain-code (0.9.2) is incompatible with client (0.10.0)`

Comment: Could you post the peer logs as well please. Also could you post the results of doing `docker ps -a`. The reason the ping fails is because the level of composer-cli you have installed is at 0.10.0 but the level of composer runtime running your business network is at 0.9.2 so they aren't compatible.

Comment: I was able to fix the ping issue easily. Deployed chain-code is now version 0.10.0. I am still having the first two errors though. I added more logs to the GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this issue is being tracked here:
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/1670